# Share a private calendar via iCal but be able to revoke access

Tags: permissions, calendar

I need to create a calendar that people can access via iCal so they can add it to their existing calendar application i.e. outlook or there Google calendar. So I could create a calendar in Google Calendar and share the URL.

I want to be able to limit who can have access the calendar. I also want to be able to revoke someone access at a later date.

The users are not all in a one company but spread out. IDeally I am looking for a free solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Up to Dec 6th 2012, you could have signed up for a FREE Google App's account, which would  happily do what you ask, going forward new subscribers need to pay per user/per month. If you don't already have an App's account I'd suggest you at least have a play with for the Trial period, as a lot less hassle than running your own alternative.

If you don't have a FREE account to play with, and have no intention on spending any beer tokens, you could spin up a [Zimbra](http://www.zimbra.com/) or [Bedework](http://www.jasig.org/bedework/features) instance on your own kit or possibly a AWS EC2 FREE tier VM, and integrate it with your own and your partner organisations set-up.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to share any Google calendar with multiple people and revoke the access individually but it might be easiest if you create a Google Group to share the calendar with then add or remove members of the Group.

After creating the calendar go to Settings/Calendars/Sharing where you will be able to add individuals by email address or an entire Google Group by group email address.

[image]
[image]

Invitees will have to create a Google account using their existing email account if it is not already a Google account. I work with a small fire department that is using a lot of Google products with their team most of whom are not on Google.

Comment: Can people then display this calendar in there outlook?

Comment: I found these instructions for subscribing to a Google Calendar using Outlook 2010.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/18353/view-your-google-calendar-in-outlook-2010/

It will only allow you to view the calendar, no changes can be made to the Google Calendar using Outlook.